# Is there a way to make site-visitor-editable text in aframe?

Tags: html, chat, aframe

I'm making a networked VR website using Aframe, and I'm trying to make a way for users to communicate via a simple line of editable text using the

```
<a-text>
```

entity. is there a way to do this, and if not, can anyone recommend ways to build a simple chat in Aframe?

```
<a-text value="Now Interactable" geometry="primitive:plane" size="5 5 5"></a-text>
```

makes the text generated interactable, but I don't know how to make it *editable*.

Comment: Please provide a test case, or what you've tried so far. People may help if you provide code and a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the `<a-text>` using `setAttribute("value", "sometext")`.

how you will provide the text (custom vr keyboard, or a typical html form) is totally up to you. Also sending the text value to other multiplayer clients is a different story.

Anyway, on whatever event just do

```
document.querySelector("a-text").setAttribute("value", newText)
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bvo6j1kz/7/).

Comment: that method doesn't seem to work with my existing code-it doesn't look like the wrapper is working. any thoughts?

Comment: @SteveJobs i only added the wrapped so i could embed the scene and show the button + form. The correct way to set the `<a-text>` value is by using `setAttribute("value", text)`, do you get any errors ?

Comment: no, it looks like it's pretty much working. thanks for your help!